# Checking in xml if node exists c#

Tags: c#, xml

I send some request and i get xml response sometimes i get

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<debt-response>
<status>0</status>
<name>ნ.ს.</name>
<schedules>
<schedule>07.07.2017 1171.8000 GEL 1</schedule>
<schedule>07.08.2017 1171.8000 GEL 1</schedule>
<schedule>07.09.2017 1171.8000 GEL 1</schedule>
</schedules>
</debt-response>
```

and sometimes i get

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<debt-response>
<status>0</status>
<name>ნ.ბ.</name>
<schedules>
<schedule>06.07.2018 1.5 GEL 1</schedule>
<debt>15.06.2018 0.97</debt>
</schedules>
</debt-response>
```

I am using var acc_numArray = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/debt-response/schedules/debt"); but if no such element exists it goes in exception.
I want to get  that debt if such node exists any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: var acc_numArray = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/debt-response/schedules/debt");

Comment: it goes in exception if nothing is returned

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include that information. Questions work best if all the necessary information is in the question itself.

Comment: Please add the actual code and show the line that is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
var debt = XDocument.Load("path to your xml").Descendants("debt").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

which gets the first `debt` element and returns its value.

If you have more than one debt, the following code saves the element values in a list:

```
var debt = XDocument.Load("path to your xml").Descendants("debt").Select(d => d.Value).ToList();
```

If you are reading the xml from a stream, use `XDocument.Parse("your string")` instead of `Load()`.

Note: you will need the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can only guess what you're doing - but one thing is certain, this line will **not** throw an exception if no nodes can be located by the specified XPath:

```
var acc_numArray = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/debt-response/schedules/debt");
```

Instead, it will return an `XmlNodeList` with a `count` of zero.

I am assuming your exception is occurring when you try and access the nodelist as if it had items in it - but simply check the count and only access it if it is non-zero:

```
var acc_numArray = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/debt-response/schedules/debt");

if (acc_numArray.Count > 0)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

If you put an example of your actual code into the question it will be a lot easier to help you.